# Edit profile detail vs change email flow

Tags: user-behavior, workflow

**The problem: client wanted a simpler flow of changing + verifying the email**

What I suggested:
"Change email" leads to a separate flow using modals, does not interfere with profile update

[image]

Client's suggestion:
"update" button will tigger both profile update, and email verification (if user changes the email), reason being it is more streamlined UX (lol)

[image]

**Just wanted to get some opinion, couldn't find the exact topic after searching around here**

Answer (score 1):

The client suggestion is cognitively simpler, having a single update process. Albeit...

> "update" button will [trigger] both...is more streamlined UX.

...may be vague—however it stands to reason two separate procedures, one for updating email and another for the rest of the fields, is inconsistent.

In order to accommodate the additional steps when also updating email, give the user advance notice of the additional email verification steps.

Initially do not display the notice if the email field has not been changed:

[image: email]

But once the email field has been altered display the "Verification required" notice:

[image: verification required]

Now, rather than having two paths/choices on the profile page for the user to contemplate and take/choose:

- Change Email
- Update

There's only one:

- Update

Answer (score 0):

I am going to side with your client in this case. The fields in your example are already in an Edit state, so the user would expect to be able to change their email here.

A natural next step after updating would be to send a verification email to the user and notify them on the next screen that they need to verify the new account. If any features become downgraded until the new email is verified, you could keep a message at the top of the screen reminding the user to check their email.

Extra modals during an editing process might lead to confusion, so keep it all in one flow.